# How center JInternalFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe

Using Java 1.8.

I use `JInternalFrame`. 
Here I set the size of the internal frame **WelcomeInternalFrame.java** .

```
public class WelcomeInternalFrame extends JInternalFrame implements ActionListener {
    private void addInternalFrame(JInternalFrame internalFrame, Boolean isMaximize, Dimension dimension) {
        desktop.add(internalFrame);
        try {
            internalFrame.setSelected(true);
            if (isMaximize != null && isMaximize) {
                internalFrame.setMaximum(true);
            } else {
                internalFrame.setSize(dimension);
            }
        } catch (java.beans.PropertyVetoException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
}
```

In my internalFrame I use `GridBagConstraints`.
The parent of my internalFrame is `JFrame`.

Here code of parent **MainScreenView.java**:

```
public class MainScreenView extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private JDesktopPane desktop;
    private void buildContent() {
            currentInternalFrame = new AccountsScroller(this);
            addInternalFrame(currentInternalFrame, true, null);
            setContentPane(desktop);

            desktop.setDragMode(JDesktopPane.OUTLINE_DRAG_MODE);

            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            pack();
            setLocationRelativeTo(null); // center
            setExtendedState(getExtendedState() | JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
            setVisible(true);
        }
}
```

This code maximize internal frame, or set specific size. OK.

But I need also to center internal frame. 
How I can do this?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: What about `setLocation`or `setBounds`? If you do not set the location of the internal frame, it will come up at 0,0 (the upper left of its container). You can use the setLocation or setBounds method to specify the upper left point of the internal frame, relative to its container.

Answer (score 1):

This question is very much dependent on the LayoutManager(s) you use. If you do *not use any* `LayoutManager`, this works:

```
private void addInternalFrame(JInternalFrame internalFrame, Boolean isMaximize, Dimension dimension) {
   try {
       internalFrame.setSelected(true);
       if (isMaximize != null && isMaximize) {
           internalFrame.setMaximum(true);
       } else {
           internalFrame.setSize(dimension);
       }
   } catch (java.beans.PropertyVetoException e) {                      
         logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
   }

    internalFrame.setLocation(desktop.getWidth()/2 - internalFrame.getWidth()/2,
        desktop.getHeight()/2 - internalFrame.getHeight()/2);
    desktop.add(internalFrame);
    internalFrame.setVisible(true);
 }
```

Telling from your other questions, I assume that `desktop`is of type `JDesktopPane`. But it would work with anything derived from `java.awt.Container`

Comment: I use JDesktopPane desktop

Comment: Not help. My internal frame is on the left upper corner.

Comment: @Alex, This should work(1+). It is just basic math to calculate the location. If it doesn't work then that probably means you set a layout manager on the desktop pane which is wrong. You need to use a null layout. You can easily verify the calculation by doing basic debugging and displaying the value of `desktop.getLocation()`.

Comment: `desktop.getLocaton` return java.awt.Point[x=0,y=0]

Comment: @Alex, sorry, I made a typo. Please take the time to understand the "context" of the suggestion. Don't assume any posted code is always accurate. You are trying to change the location of the internal frame. So don't you think it would make sense to check the actual location of the internal frame so see if you calculation worked as expected?

Comment: I found solution: `Dimension dimensionScreen = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
  Dimension weclomeSCreenDimension = new Dimension(500, 400);
  currentInternalFrame = new WelcomeInternalFrame(this);
  currentInternalFrame.setLocation(
    (int) ((dimensionScreen.getWidth() / 2) - (weclomeSCreenDimension.getWidth() / 2)),
    (int) ((dimensionScreen.getHeight() / 2) - (weclomeSCreenDimension.getHeight() / 2)));`